# rendering env-var inside kubernetes kubeconfig yaml file

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, kubeconfig

I need to use an environment variable inside my kubeconfig file to point the `NODE_IP` of the Kubernetes API server.

My config is:

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    insecure-skip-tls-verify: true
    server: https://$NODE_IP:6443
  name: docker-for-desktop-cluster
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: docker-for-desktop-cluster
    user: docker-for-desktop
  name: docker-for-desktop
current-context: docker-for-desktop
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: docker-for-desktop
  user:
......
```

But it seems like the kubeconfig file is not getting rendered variables when I run the command:

```sh
kubectl --kubeconfig mykubeConfigFile get pods.
```

It complains as below:

> Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp: lookup $NODE_IP: no such host

Did anyone try to do something like this or is it possible to make it work?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can do `kubectl --kubeconfig mykubeConfigFile --server "https://${NODE_IP}:6443" get pods`. Read more about kubeconfig [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/organize-cluster-access-kubeconfig/)

Comment: @Amit thanks a lot for the response and editing my post, but I think helm is not supporting the --server option.
I share my output of helm command below.
Error: unknown flag: --server

But anyway I dont know how happened but my problem is solved.
I am able to upload helmchart within the pod with deafult kubeconfig configuration.
So I didnt have to pass the new kubeconfig file anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/791715/using-environment-variables-in-kubernetes-deployment-spec) contains explanations and answers:

- ... either [wait](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/23896) [Implement templates · Issue #23896 · kubernetes/kubernetes](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/23896) for [the implementation of the templating proposal](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/proposals/templates.md) in `k8s` ([not](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/24777) merged yet)
- ... or preprocess your yaml with tools like:

  - `envsubst`:

  ```sh
  export NODE_IP="127.0.11.1"
  envsubst < mykubeConfigFile.yml | kubectl --kubeconfig mykubeConfigFile.yml get pods
  ```

  - `sed`:

  ```sh
  cat mykubeConfigFile.yml | sed s/\$\$EXTERNAL_IP/127.0.11.1/ | kubectl --kubeconfig mykubeConfigFile.yml get pods
  ```

Comment: thx for the suggestion. As I described I didnt have to pass kubeconfig file to the command finally. I have no idea why. 
But if i needed again envsubst is a solid solution i missed it.